# Response status code does not indicate success: 401 in the task "restore" on the azure-pipeline

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I have the following error:

```
error : Unable to load the service index for source https://privateLibrary.com/private/_packaging/privateOrganitation/nuget/v3/index.json. [/home/vsts/work/1/s/Local.Proyect.Core/Local.Proyect.Core.csproj]
       /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.101/NuGet.targets(123,5): 
error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [/home/vsts/work/1/s/Local.Proyect.Core/Local.Proyect.Core.csproj]
```

My azure-pipeline.yml:

```
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  localProyectName: 'Local.Proyect.Core'
  localProyectCoreDirectory: './Local.Proyect.Core'


trigger:
 branches:
   include:
     - master

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/$(localProyectName).csproj'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: $(localProyectCoreDirectory)/NuGet.Config
    arguments: --force

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'Build All'
  inputs:
    projects: '**/$(localProyectName).csproj'
    arguments: '--no-restore --configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- script: dotnet publish --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(localProyectName) ./$(localProyectName)/$(localProyectName).csproj
  displayName: 'dotnet publish of project $(localProyectName)'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: $(localProyectName)'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(localProyectName)'
    ArtifactName: '$(localProyectName)'
```

The error start in command restore. As you can see in azure devops machine can´t restore mi private packets. I am using the NuGet.Config **inside my app** "Local.Proyect.Core" with the URL of the organitation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageRestore>
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="privateOrgnitation" value="https://privateLibrary.com/private/_packaging/privateOrganitation/nuget/v3/index.json." />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
  </packageSources>
  <bindingRedirects>
    <add key="skip" value="False" />
  </bindingRedirects>
  <packageManagement>
    <add key="format" value="0" />
    <add key="disabled" value="False" />
  </packageManagement>
</configuration>
```

Why the machine can´t find my Azure Artifacts in OTHER organitation?? And why I haven't got any error in visual studio and here yes...

Comment: Thank you for the support, I actually don't resolved the issue! But I found some information and I look foward to also find the problem. I think that my host terminal (PC) is configured and is authorized to use the private dependencies but the devops cloud machine not. I really don't know how is configured the "private organitation" of devops and how share these private nuget packets. After find the solution I will post here.

Comment: Fine, looking forward to your answer.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue, would you mind share the solution as answer to us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, after wait a long time away since I have had this problem, I resolved this with an internal organization of my code and the NuGet packages artifacts. The problem was that in devops my packages were in a different organization and it was a private repository. So, now when the azure machine needs a artifact, nuget can take it and use to build my project.

Comment: How can I move the packages across organizations?

Comment: More details on the fix would be appreciated for the wider audience

Answer (score 3):

This problem can also occur if your password has changed.

Reset your cached credentials via the Credentials Manager in Windows: **Control Panel → All Control Panel Items → Credential Manager**. Below **Windows Credentials** remove any entry with a name like `VSCredentials_<domain>`.

Then try building again; Visual Studio should ask for your current password.

Comment: II had a similar solution. Just went into Visual Studio to re-enter my credentials. You can force this by clicking on your account photo on top right of Visual Studio > Account Settings. Note the option is not visible once credentials correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Response status code does not indicate success: 401 in the task “restore” on the azure-pipeline

According to the error info:

> `Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)`

It seems you are not provide the credentials for a package source in `nuget.config`, you can try to provide the credential in the `nuget.config`, like:

```
<packageSourceCredentials>
    <privateOrgnitation>
        <add key="Username" value="user@contoso.com" />
        <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="YourPassword" />
    </privateOrgnitation>
</packageSourceCredentials>
```

Check the document [packageSourceCredentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#packagesourcecredentials) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Im trying to use this approach, but still throwing 401, differences are that instead of "privateOrganization" I have "privateLibrary", probably you meant that. In addition, is not quite clear how to get the password, are you expecting this password to be the ones created under "Service Connections" in ADO?